# Is it possible to define specific variable mask in DBeaver?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I have a variables in my SQL code which look like that:

```
select * from $${schema_name}$$.table_name;
```

So it's *$${variable}$$*, which is this way because that's how it's defined to be is used in another tool used for scheduling the SQL code runs.

Is it possible to create a variable or parameter which will automatically use the correct value for that $${}$$ construction? When I try to run it DBeaver automatically suggests to use the **${name}** mask: [image: auto formatting from DBeaver] which doesn't suit me, and when I try to hardcode it in ["Variable" Panel](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Variables-panel/), it fails to compile the code, doesn't replace it.